# Analyze Maven pom with SonarQube

Tags: maven, sonarqube

Can I analyze pom files correctness using Sonar? ([like the maven enforcer plugin rules](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is *no*. The slightly longer answer is *maybe*. There is no plugin listed on the office [plugins page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Plugin+Library) with this functionality, but it's possible to write a plugin that could run some rules on a maven project and report the issues as like with any other metric...